# TabView caching or reloading startegy

Tags: angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have encountered the following behavior and trying to understand how caching and loading of contents of a TabViewItem work in nativescript angular.

I have a few TabViewItems (A, B, C, D). I have a property in a global dto object accessed  through an angular service, lets call it 'propertyA' in tab B and the same property in Tab C. I change the property in tab C and the property is correctly updated in tab B. I change the property in Tab B, i click on tab C and the property is **NOT** updated in tab C. The strange thing is that if i click on tab A and then on tab C the property **IS** updated.

Through console.log statements it seems that Tab C contents are loaded when i click on tab B and I assume they are not loaded when i click on tab C from tab B. Whereas i assume that when i click on tab A and then tab C i force reloading.

I can't see how this will affect my real application so i will put it on hold for the time-being (strict deadline :) ) but I would appreciate it if there are any ideas/workarounds to try...

kind regards,
Thomas.

Note: I can't post the whole project but here are the dependencies of my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~6.1.0",
"@angular/common": "~6.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~6.1.0",
"@angular/core": "~6.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "~6.1.0",
"@angular/http": "~6.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~6.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~6.1.0",
"@angular/router": "~6.1.0",
"guid-typescript": "^1.0.7",
"lodash": "^4.17.11",
"nativescript-angular": "~6.1.0",
"nativescript-imagepicker": "~6.0.0",
"nativescript-plugin-firebase": "~6.0.0",
"nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
"nativescript-ui-listview": "~3.7.0",
"reflect-metadata": "~0.1.10",
"rxjs": "~6.2.0",
"tns-core-modules": "~4.2.0",
"zone.js": "~0.8.18"},
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to know the component [lifecycle](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/374) here that how angular destroys the element and uses the cached clement.
But in case you want to update 'PropertyA' in all the tabs as soon it gets updated in any of the tab,Instead of a shared global object you can create a observer and subscribe to it in each tabitem

Comment: Thanks Narendra. I think you are spot on but i have one question. Is the lifecycle of components within tabs the same as for pages ie is every tab treated as a different page?

Comment: I am under impression that each of the tab items gets treatment as an individual component that is why Back button takes to you to previous tab and it may depend on your implementation as well. Thers is one very good example [here](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/using-nested-router-outlets-with-nativescript-and-angular) using nativescript and angular.